# Objects inside singletons in .Net

Tags: .net, memory, memory-management, singleton

To give a real example. Here is the following class:

```
public class HttpClientWrapper : IHttpClientWrapper
{
    private static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private readonly IStatsDPublisher _statsDPublisher;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public HttpClientWrapper(IStatsDPublisher statsDPublisher, string baseAddress)
    {
        _statsDPublisher = statsDPublisher;
        _client = new HttpClient();


        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
        ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(_client.BaseAddress).ConnectionLeaseTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60).TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    public async Task PostAsync<T>(string resource, T content)
    {
        var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content), Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");

        var name = typeof(T);

        using (var timer = _statsDPublisher.StartTimer($"HttpClient.{name.Name}.Post"))
        {
            try
            {
                await _client.PostAsync(resource, stringContent).ContinueWith(
                    (postTask) =>
                    {
                        postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    });

                timer.StatName = $"{timer.StatName}.Success";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                timer.StatName = $"{timer.StatName}.Failure";
                Logger.ExtendedException(ex, "Failed to Post.", new {Url = resource, Content = content});
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task PutAsync<T>(string resource, T content)
    {
        var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content), Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json");

        var name = typeof(T);

        using (var timer = _statsDPublisher.StartTimer($"HttpClient.{name.Name}.Put"))
        {
            try
            {
                await _client.PutAsync(resource, stringContent).ContinueWith(
                   (postTask) =>
                   {
                       postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                   });

                timer.StatName = $"{timer.StatName}.Success";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                timer.StatName = $"{timer.StatName}.Failure";
                Logger.ExtendedException(ex, "Failed to Put.", new { Url = resource, Content = content });
                throw;
            }
         }
    }
```

}
}

In the IoC we do the following :

```
 Bind<IHttpClientWrapper>()
                .To<HttpClientWrapper>()
                .InSingletonScope()
```

So now is a singleton. Should I assume that every time we call the HttpClientWrapper, are we dealing with same instance of HttpClient, or every time we are creating a new one? I believe that ever time you access HttpClientWrapper, despite being Singleton, you create a new instance of HttpClient. Can you please advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singleton means, that you only have one single instance of a class in your whole application. You simply cannot create another instance of that class. And working with objects inside your singleton will always return the very same instances.
However, you can still create new instances of the other classes outside of your singleton.
So the answer is obviously "no".

Hope that helps.

Comment: Singleton means one instance. That is clear. So, you are saying that A and B object inside OrderApiClient are NOT singletons but every time you are calling OrderAPiCLient, you have one instance of it, but inside this class , you create new instances of A and B. Correct?

Comment: Let's talk more consisely. Given your class `OrderApiClient` creates a new instance of class `A` when it is created. Your code accesses `OrderApiClient.A` through a property, which returns the instance created at instantiation of `OrderApiClient`. So you will always have the same Instance of A, without `A`being a singleton. You could also always create new instances of `A`in `OrderApiClient`, or anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  If however you have a method inside your singleton class that does :                                                                       publc Get A(string address) { var a =  new A(); return a;} . You do create new instance a A and your singleton will return a new instance of A. Am i wrong to conclude that your singleton OrderApiClient will return new instances of A?

Comment: Correct. When always creating new instances, you will get new instances :-)

Comment: thanks :). Above is some code. The argument occurred today as someone implied that because we are using HttpClient inside a singleton, by default it will also be singleton. If that was the case, then HttpClient would error. Not sure exactly , but it seems that this person is really convinced that HttpClient will also be singleton.

Comment: Oh. Given the code above, you actually _will_ always work with the same instance everytime you call `PutAsync`and `PostAsync`. You only create `HttpClient`once (in the constructor of your class). If you would create a new instance with every call, you would always use a fresh instance (which would be better anyway).

Comment: So, if I have two different baseAddresses i.e OrdersAPI and CustomersAPI, it WILL NOT work for both of them, it will work only for whoever gets first to call the HttpClientWrapper. So all subsequent calls to HttpClientWrapper, will be using same BaseAddess.  =In that xase, since I have to use many base addresses for various API's, I should NOT be using HttpClientWrapper as singleton.

Comment: Right. You should only do that, when you only need that one single flavor.